# How to substring every element in vector of strings?

Tags: r, vector

I have the vector:

```
v <- c("godzilla", "jurassic", "googly")
```

I want the first 3 letters of every element in this vector. I would like to end up with:

```
# "god"   "jur"   "goo"
```

I have already tried using `apply`, but it didn't work. What should I do?

Comment: See, @agstudy  you got answer-bombed by Gavin :-)

Answer (score 13):

One option is `substring()`:

```
> substring(v, first = 1, last = 3)
[1] "god" "jur" "goo"
```

or also the R version, `substr()`

```
> substr(v, start = 1, stop = 3)
[1] "god" "jur" "goo"
```

Note the different names for the initial and last character you want.

As both of these functions are vectorised, there is no need for `apply()` and friends here.

Comment: How would one apply this to vectors within the rows of a data.frame? When I apply to a column by `df2 <- df1 %>% mutate(y = substr(x, 0, 4))`, I end up with the beginning of the concatenated list and the first characters of the first element of the list, e.g. `"c("12" "c("24" "c("34"`.

Answer (score 10):

For the fun you can use a regular expression here :

```
sub('(^.{3}).*','\\1',v)
[1] "god" "jur" "goo"
```

Which is a another vectorized solution.

Comment: Powerful, yet simple! +1

Comment: Though this gets ugly if the length (`3`) is variable: `sub(paste0('(^.{', len, '}).*'),'\\1',v)` vs. `substr(v, 1, len)`...

Answer (score 3):

@Gavin Simpson's answer is the right way to go, but if you want to use `apply()` and friends  here, you can try the following:

```
> sapply(strsplit(v, ""), function(x) paste0(x[1:3], collapse=""))
[1] "god" "jur" "goo"
```

Comment: gah. want to award points for curiosity but wouldn't want anyone to actually *use* this answer!

Comment: Yeah, this is just for fun.

Comment: This is the best answer to me, it helps you understand how functional programming works on R.

Answer (score 1):

A `stringr` option is `str_sub`:

```r
str_sub(v, 1, 3)
#[1] "god" "jur" "goo"
```

And `str_sub_all` for multiple substrings in each string:

```r
str_sub_all(v, c(1, 2), c(3, 4))
# [[1]]
# [1] "god" "odz"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "jur" "ura"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "goo" "oog"
```